# Benchmark Javascript: onclick in tag vs click in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, benchmarking

I can undestand work javascript to performance.

What is the difference?

```
$('#button').click(function() { }
```

vs

```
<a href="" onclick="javascript:action"></a>
```

I understand is called the same function, but if i have first option and javascript scan all attributes on mouseover and checking all time is it this #button?

I understand is doesn't matter for #id, but if have more .class is maybe be problem.?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here actually is but I get the feeling that appropriate responses are "Don't prematurely optimise" and "Benchmark it yourself".

Comment: Why would you benchmark this? 
The grammatical option is way slower, while behavior is similar. 
The behavior of first and second option is diffrent. - it makes this up as it is the way to develop javascript applications and separates html from code (behavior), allows more event handlers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

the first is a jquery aproach to addEventListener ( a more shorter way ) the second is the change of an inline attribute for the element which applies an event. Basically it is the same, now it deppends how the browser implements it, but from what i have tried using addEventListener is more reliable than inline attribute if you need at some point to remove the listener, if it will stay that way to the end of times or you do not need some high js behind you just use the inline version for faster uses and for better readability.

Comment: Thx, i needed "addEventListener". What's mean "high js"?. In my benchmark i wonted to  reduce EventListener by inline attribute in simple solution, Example: 100elements after click -> send ajax. Maybe click (inline for one elements from 100 is slow) vs EventListener,  but all code on the web can by feel slim, which using EventListener.